# bash variable expansion in for loop sub-command

Tags: bash, kubectl

Trying to expand a for loop variable in this does not succeed -
I am trying to use the $i variable in the jsonpath for loop below:

```
for i in {0..9}; do 
    echo $i
    kubectl exec -i -t "$(kubectl get pod -l "app=mdm-shard" -o jsonpath='{.items[{$i}].metadata.name}')" -- cat /proc/net/udp
done
```

I get:

```
0
error: error parsing jsonpath {.items[{$i}].metadata.name}, invalid array index {$i}
error: pod name must be specified
```

I tried a lot of combinations but can't find the one that is going to expand $i inside the query.

My bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Single quotes suppress parameter expansion, use `jsonpath="{...}"` instead.

Comment: And probably `$i` instead of `{$i}`.

Comment: You can see there's something wrong with the quoting even here with the syntax highlighting. You need to be much more careful with the quotes;)

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: @liborm Care to elaborate? The syntax highlighting is just due to the fact that the highlighter doesn't know that `$(...)` starts a new quoting context.

Comment: You perhaps want to use `jq --arg i "${i}"`, then reference `$i` inside your _single-quoted_ JQ directive.

Comment: @chepner neither I knew ;) But substituting `'` with `"` is really enough, as @Benjamin suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Benjamin - yes this worked:

```sh
for i in {0..9}; do 
  echo $i
  kubectl exec -i -t "$(kubectl get pod -l "app=mdm-shard" -o jsonpath="{.items[$i].metadata.name}")" -- cat /proc/net/udp; 
done
```